# bash :: use imported array

Tags: bash, array, var

```
    myVAR='myArr'

. ./myArraysFile # external file with all my arrays, one of the arrays is myArr=('one' 'two' 'three')
```

---

I need to use this arrey with further scripting

Examples:

```
echo ${!myVAR}[1]  # I want it to print 'two'
```

or

```
for here in 'place.one' 'place.two';do
    ssh ${!myVAR}[7]@$here
done
```

and so one

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1397146/432690).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` release 4.3 or later, then use a name reference variable instead:

```bsh
source ./myArraysFile

declare -n myVAR=myArr
printf '%s\n' "${myVAR[1]}"
```

The variable `myVAR` above is a name reference variable, declared with `declare -n` and the value `myArr`.  This means that each access to `myVAR` will access `myArr`.

Comment: awesome. all works now. thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @eswues you should consider to accept the answers if it help you.